# react router v4 route changed but did not render the correct component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have 2 level of route, the first layer it look like this

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <div>
    <AuthRoute></AuthRoute>
    <Switch>
      <Route path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

where in AuthRoute I have a redirect upon componentDidMount
`this.props.history.replace(`/dashboard/redirected`)`

The problem is within the dashboard/index which is my 2nd level of route config

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path='/dashboard' component={()=><h1>dashboard index</h1>} />
    <Route exact path='/dashboard/somewhere' component={()=><h1>somewhere</h1>} />
    <Route exact path='/dashboard/redirected' component={() => <h1>redirected</h1>} />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

The route changed to `/dashboard/redirect` but the component didn't render the correct one if you refresh on says `/dashboard/somewhere` or `/dashboard/`

You can see the problem clearer in the demo I setup https://codesandbox.io/s/v0v4qok38l

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one `<BrowserRouter>` in the application - removing it from `dashboard/index.js` will fix your issue.